# How did online banking work before Netscape added support for JavaScript and cookies in September 1995?

Tags: javascript, cookies, e-commerce, banking, netscape

Quite a few websites mentioned the availability of online banking from Stanford Federal Credit Union as early as October 1994.  However, Netscape added JavaScript/cookies support in September 1995.  How was online banking possible without cookies?

#### Sources:

- https://www.forbes.com/advisor/banking/what-is-digital-banking/
- https://www.ubs.com/ch/en/wealth-management/womens-wealth/academy/2022/history-of-digital-banking.html
- https://cointelegraph.com/news/a-brief-history-of-digital-banking

Comment: They used hidden inputs or query parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before cookies, state was maintained using URL query parameters or hidden inputs in the form.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any internet sources for these information?

Comment: My personal memory of writing web pages in the 1990's. When I wanted to keep state, I sent it in the URL.

Comment: Basically, it's the only way to do it. That's what cookies automated.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar.  Since I am writing a research paper on this topic, what would be some internet sources for these information?  If there were no internet sources, what books or magazines would be the best source of information?

Comment: Good luck finding information about how to write web sites 30 years ago.